# insert meteor.userId into mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I want to initialize a field in simpleSchema. I want set userId into a string field.

here is the schema:

```
AdsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title"
  },
  insertedBy: {
    type: String,
    label: "Inserted By",
    autoform:{
      type:"hidden"
    },
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.userId) {
        return this.userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but after inserting by autoform, the inserted document is:

```
{
    "_id" : "Zm5TML5bwJhyN8B9F",
    "title" : "test"
}
```

it means "insertedBy" field has "null" value!

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `if(Meteor.userId()) return Meteor.userId()`

`this` in autoValue has limited Properties, check the Doc [Autoform Docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue)

Gave a little study on autoValue , Under `cleaning Data` there is a mention of property `extendAutoValueContext` which helps to use userId
.

Comment: I use Meteor.userId() instead of this.userId , and problem solved. thanks